# Does sass have a way to replace the @plugin function of less？

Tags: sass, less

less has @plugin grammar, I want to change it to sass, how can I do it?

I want to migrate less @plugin to Sass

for example:
@plugin "./palette";
@red-1: color-palette(@red-6, 1);

the color-palette function is a js plugin, how can i use in sass?

Answer (score 0):

Less's [`@plugin`](https://lesscss.org/features/#plugin-atrules-feature) lets you add functions and features into `.less` files. I believe the equivalent for SASS would be the [`@function`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/function) at-rule. Instead of writing the functions in JS, you can write them in SASS directly and [`@use`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) them in your other files.

I have no idea what your `color-palette` function do so this is just a random example:

**_palette.scss**

```
@function color($color, $opacity) {
  ...
  @return ...
}
```

**other-file.scss**

```
@use "palette";

$red-6: palette.color(red, 0.6);
$red-1: palette.color($red-6, 1);
```